# Arabic language doesn't show probably on Android Studio 2.3 XML preview

Tags: android, xml, localization, android-studio-2.3

When use Arabic strings in my xml files it doesn't show probably when use in edittext hint attribute only, but attribute text is working fine, any idea to solve this issue ?

[image]

My XML looks like this

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/userNameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/userNameET"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
            android:hint="@string/first_name_text"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

My strings.xml looks like

```
    <resources>

    <string name="user_name_text">أسم المستخدم</string>
    <string name="first_name_text">الاسم الأول</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: add your xml !!

Comment: done i added my xml

Comment: add you strings folder

Comment: done i added my strings.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Confirmed as [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=234997) by google team!

---

After trying to figure out what the problem is, here is what I have got:

It looks like to be an issue with

```
android:hint="@string/string_name"
```

When it is inside `TextInputLayout`, it is not rendering the `rtl` text! and I don't know why [I think it is a bug in Android studio]

**look at this `xml` layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_screen_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
        android:hint="@string/TextString"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="20dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
            android:hint="@string/TextString" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/TextString"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

if you tried to view it in Android studio's `xml` editor, it will be not render correctly [see frame 1 in the below pic]

But if you compiled and run the App n a device it is rendered normally [see frame 2 in the below pic]!

[image]

Comment: Yes same case happened to me apparently its an android studio bug related to version 2.3 will try to report this bug .. thanks anyway for help.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37136729),This has been fixed. This is available since **Android studio 3.0.0 Canary 6 build**.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37136729) they will re-open to examine.